# What does data="@/some/path" mean in Python?

Tags: python, string, binary, format-string

This is from some code I'm looking at... I think it's some sort of special format string that loads the file at the path into a binary string assigned to data, but I'm not sure as when I try to replicate it all I get is a standard string. Or is it actually a standard string and I'm reading too much into it?

Comment: That's not Python syntax. It might be specific to the code you're looking at.  What is the code?  What is the context? Help us help you!

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. This is something that gets passed to Twisted eventually to POST to a server.

Comment: Could you post the actual code?

Comment: In the end if seems to just be a marker but using it got my code to work. The code I was using as an example is: api.anymeta.attachment.create(mime="image/jpeg", data="@/home/arjan/televisie.jpg", title="A nice television", connect=connect)

Comment: @pr1001: Please don't post code in a comment.  It's unreadable.  Please **update** your question to be complete and correct.  Please **update** your question to include the relevant code.

Comment: One **update** got the point across. ;-p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually just a string.